# How do I count duplicate array values and return their index locations?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have two arrays that have correlated data. The arrays are being filled with data from an excel spread sheet using xlrd. The two arrays are:

```
foundLocations['D47', 'D33', 'D33', 'D35', 'PM001']
foundCounts['240.0', '105.0', '24.0', '56.0', '92.0']
```

These values change all the time, but as you can see 'D33' appears twice in this example.

I would like to add the values of foundCounts[1] and foundCounts[2] (in this example) together to get the total for location 'D33', as well as the other locations. So 'D47' would have 240.0 pieces. 'D33' would have 129.0 pieces. 'D35' would have 56.0 pieces. And 'PM001' would have 92.0 pieces.

Expected output:
D33 total: 129.0 
D35 total: 56.0 
D47 total: 240.0  
PM001 total: 92.0

I've tried converting the arrays to a numpy array and doing this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

a = array(foundLocations)
for r in foundLocations:
    searchval = r
    ii = np.where(a == searchval)[0]
    print(foundCounts[ii])
```

But I get:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
>   index.

Comment: look at np.unique ?

Comment: what is `foundLocs`?

Comment: Sorry...I edited it. It's supposed to be foundLocations

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a dictionary as a final result, so it's not clear that numpy is really the right choice.

Here's a non-numpy way to do this to get a dictionary of totals. This just adds to each key using [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to insure each key is defined and the total starts at zero:

```
foundLocations = ['D47', 'D33', 'D33', 'D35', 'PM001']
foundCounts = ['240.0', '105.0', '24.0', '56.0', '92.0']

totals = {}
for loc, count in zip(foundLocations, foundCounts):
    totals[loc] = totals.setdefault(loc, 0) + float(count)

totals
```

**Output:**

```
{'D47': 240.0, 'D33': 129.0, 'D35': 56.0, 'PM001': 92.0}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was getting fed up with numpy. Maybe it's my lack of understanding of it. But thank you kind sir! Dictionary is what I needed.